# Erro Undefined variable php

Tags: php

Estou com uma pagina que busca os produtos no banco e me exibe na index através de um include ou seja index.php mostra o include com os produtos.
tenho no include uma opção de pesquisar por nome os produtos no banco.
como ele seta página separada de pesquisa eu não sei como fazer ela abrir na index.
tão Logo trouxe os valores de busca no banco para a da pagina dando include o problema ta sendo o seguinte:
Na mesma Página ele ta trazendo o valor dos produtos do banco para exibir 
e tbm trazendo o valor da busca dos produtos.
creio que esteja rolando o conflito pos funciona mostrando a mensagem de erro no index. mas se eu pesquiso ele traz o resultado e fica normal sem erro.

```
<?php include_once("conexao_produtos.php");
//Verificar se está sendo passado na URL a página atual, senao é atribuido a pagina 
$pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;
if(!isset($_GET['pesquisar'])){
}else{
    $valor_pesquisar = $_GET['pesquisar'];
}

/* TRAZ OS PRODUTOS DO BANCO PARA SEREM MOSTRADOS */
//Selecionar todos os cursos da tabela
$result_curso = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE prod_nome LIKE '%$valor_pesquisar%'";
$resultado_curso = mysqli_query($conn, $result_curso);

//Contar o total de cursos
$total_cursos = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_curso);

//Seta a quantidade de cursos por pagina
$quantidade_pg = 6;

//calcular o número de pagina necessárias para apresentar os cursos
$num_pagina = ceil($total_cursos/$quantidade_pg);

//Calcular o inicio da visualizacao
$incio = ($quantidade_pg*$pagina)-$quantidade_pg;
/* TRAZ OS PRODUTOS DO BANCO PARA SEREM MOSTRADOS EM CASO DE BUSCA */
//Selecionar os cursos a serem apresentado na página
$result_cursos = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE prod_nome LIKE '%$valor_pesquisar%' limit $incio, $quantidade_pg";
$resultado_cursos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cursos);
$total_cursos = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_cursos);
?>
```

como ele me apresenta que ta aparentando erro na linha 17 e na 33 
a 17 tenho o resultado dos produtos :

```
$result_curso = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE prod_nome LIKE '%$valor_pesquisar%'";
insira o código aqui
```

Na 33 o da pesquisa.

```
$result_cursos = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE prod_nome LIKE '%$valor_pesquisar%' limit $incio, $quantidade_pg";
```

Comment: tem esse tipo de problema se você coloca dois results na mesma página?

Comment: Leo, li e li e não entendi o problema que esta tendo...

Comment: estou com esses dois results ai colocados na mesma tag no php eles tão me apresentando como se estivessem com problema mas estão exibindo normal mesmo com a mensagem Notice: Undefined variable: valor_pesquisar in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\imperionutry\index_produtos.php on line 17    e tbm na linha 33 mas se eu faço uma busca ele para de me apresentar a mensagem de erro e exibe normal mas só com o resultado da busca que no caso é a lina 33

Comment: mas os resultados estao exibindo normal?

Comment: exibia sim normal o amigo ajudou eu não tinha passado os parametros para ele  em caso de não existir a busca fiz como se ela existisse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso é uma coisa meio boba, se é o que eu acho que esta acontecendo. Acontece porque as vezes a variavel com o valor a ser buscado, as vezes nao vai existir em alguns contextos, mas é carregada da mesma forma. Uma solução simples é verificar se ela existe antes de atribuir o valor
assim:

```
//passo o valor para a variavel sómente se o get existir
$valor_pesquisar = isset($_GET['pesquisar'])?isset($_GET['pesquisar']):'';
```

No caso ali voce fez a verificação, voce veirificou só quando ela existe, e quando nao, simplesmente nao fez nada, entao se ela nao existir, a sua variavel tambem nao vai existir, ou seja o seu if nao valeu em nada. Outra soluçao seria voce colocar toda a sua pesquisa dentro do else lá...
Espero ter ajudado

Comment: era isso mesmo mano Obg,

Comment: Ok amigo, ajudou e muito.

Comment: @LeoAndrade De nada, é um prazer ajudar :)